# elasticsearch filter dates based on datetime fields

Tags: date, datetime, elasticsearch

assuming I have the following nested document structure, where my document contains nested routes with an array of date time values.

```
     {
       property_1: ...,
       routes: [ 
         { 
           start_id: 1,
           end_id: 2,
           execution_times: ['2016-08-28T11:11:47+02:00', ...]
         }
       ]
     }
```

Now I could filter my documents that match certain execution_times with something like this.

```
     query: {
       filtered: {
         query: {
           match_all: { }
        },
        filter: {
          nested: {
            path: 'routes',
            filter: {
              bool: {
                must: [
                  {
                    terms: {
                      'routes.execution_times': ['2016-08-28T11:11:47+02:00', ...]
                    }
                  },
                  ...
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But what if I would like to filter my documents based on execution dates. What's the best way achieving this?

Should I use a range filter to map my dates to time ranges?

Or is it better to use a script query and do a conversion of the execution_times to dates there?

Or is the best way to change the document structure to contain both, the execution_date and execution_time?

Comment: So basically I would like to have a way to compare my date time fields with a date. In SQL you simply would use a date function: `WHERE date(date_time_field) = '01.01.2012'`

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

"The dates are not a range but individual dates like [today, day after tomorrow, 4 days from now, 10 days from now]"

Well, this is still a range as a day means 24 hours. So if you store your field as date time, you can use leverage range query : from 20-Nov-2010 00:00:00 TO 20-Nov-2010 23:59:59 with appropriate time zone for a specific day.

If you store it as a String then you will lose all the flexibility of date maths and you would be able to do only exact String matches. You will then have to do all the date manipulations at the client side to find exact matches and ranges.

I suggest play with range queries using Sense plugin and I am sure it will satisfy almost all your requirements.

### -----------------------

You should make sure that you use appropriate date-time mapping for your field and use range filter over that field. You don't need to split into 2 separate fields. Date maths will allow you to query just based on date.

This will make your life much easier if you want to do aggregations over date time field.

Reference:

Date Maths:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math

Date Mapping : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

Date Range Queries:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: But when I want to filter the date-time values my multiple dates such as I could using the terms filter I would have to use a range filter for each date. When I filter for 10 dates I would have to use 10 range filters. Would that still be efficient?

Comment: Can you please help with your 2 most common use cases/queries ?

Comment: Well I'm trying to filter documents based on multiple given dates (in combination with other filters) using the date time fields in the routes. Meaning I would like to find documents that contain routes with certain execution times. The dates are not a range but individual dates like [today, day after tomorrow, 4 days from now, 10 days from now]

Comment: Does anybody know which date-format standard is Elasticsearch using? I can use *"tomorrow"* but that is not mentioned anywhere, so I guess it comes from some other broadly accepted standard that ES uses...